# Error: variable or field 'functionName' declared void

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, header-files

I have the following in a C++ header file, as shown below.

cmdtree.h:

```
#ifndef CMDTREE_H
#define CMDTREE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "functions.h"      // different header where some functions are
#include "classes.h"        // different header where classes are
using namespace std;

void printLine(string filename, int line);
void cmd_ask_name();
void cmd_look_suspect();

#endif  /* CMDTREE_H */
```

Then, in a .cpp source file, I have the following typed *exactly* as below (with some filler from other extraneous functions cut out for brevity). There are no includes, nothing else but what's shown here. I'm wondering, also, if *that* was the right decision, but I've tried it several different ways so I just thought I'd give you the cleanest version of the error:

cmdtree.cpp:

```
void printLine(string filename, int line)
{
    char        descrip[11][500] = {0};
    char        *ch_arr = descrip[0];
    fstream     text;
    int         y = 0;

    cout << "\nfile: " << filename << " line: " << line << endl;

    text.open(filename,ios::in);
    if (!text.is_open()) {         
        cout << "\nCould not open " << filename << "." << endl;
    } else {
        while (!text.eof())
        {
            ch_arr = descrip[y];
            text.getline(ch_arr,500);
            y++;
        }                
    }
    text.close();
    ch_arr = descrip[line];
    cout    << " " << ch_arr << endl;

}

void cmd_ask_name() 
{      

}

void cmd_look_suspect()     // look suspect
{

}
```

Upon compilation, I receive the following errors. The cause isn't obvious to me -- I've included  in the header file. I even get the error when I include string at the top of the cpp file itself.

```
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cmdtree.o.d"
g++    -c -g -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cmdtree.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cmdtree.o cmdtree.cpp
cmdtree.cpp:3:16: error: variable or field 'printLine' declared void
 void printLine(string filename, int line)
                ^
cmdtree.cpp:3:16: error: 'string' was not declared in this scope
cmdtree.cpp:3:33: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
 void printLine(string filename, int line)
                                 ^
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:70: recipe for target 'build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cmdtree.o' failed
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cmdtree.o] Error 1
```

Comment: You included `cmdtree.h` in your `cmdtree.cpp` file, right?

Comment: I did it both ways and still got the compiler error -- with the header included in the .cpp and without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're missing the following from your cmdtree.cpp:

```
#include "cmdtree.h"
```

It doesn't get included automatically just because it has the same root file name as the .cpp file.

Also, it's not a good idea to put "using namespace std;" in a header file.  Rather explicitly use std::string in the header and then you can put "using namespace std;" in the .cpp file.

Comment: I received the compiler error when I placed this include at the top of cmdtree.cpp, as well, unfortunately.

Comment: Correction. I just replaced the include and *that* particular issue is resolved, but now it's throwing "not declared" errors for structures declared elsewhere in the file.

Comment: Make sure that the other structures are declared in the header file (or before where you use them).

Comment: They are :( It's been a recurring issue. I'll post up a seperate question about the issue in some time. Thanks.